# Angular 2: Component loading issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

My project has the below structure

[image]

I want to call "header-component.component.html" from "login-component.component.html" but I am getting an error as below:

***compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'header-component' is not a known element:***

my **login-component.component.html** is as below:

```
    <header-component></header-component>
        I am a login page with above header
```

and my **header-component.component.html** is below:

```
hi I am header
```

Can anyone please guide me where I am wrong?

Also below is my login-component.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-component',
  templateUrl: './login-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-component.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: try `app-header-component`, which is likely the correct selector

Comment: The selector of your component is probably `app-header-component`, not `header-component`. Also, please drop this double component suffix: the files should be named header.component.xxx, and the class should be named HeaderComponent, not HeaderComponentComponent. Same for the login. If using the CLI to henerate components, use `ng generate component fo`, not `ng generate component foo-component`.

Comment: if not added already, then add `HeaderComponent` in your module declarations.

Comment: Can you share the `@Compomemt` part of your `header.component.ts` please? Are you exporting it correctly?

Comment: @MichaelHancock thanks issue solved

Comment: @JBNizet thanks issue solved, thanks for the corrected naming conventions I will now follow them